Is it possible to store large data arrays in a single cell for future reference in Google Sheets?
The current formula returns 2 columns and multiple rows. I want to store the result in a single "data cell" for future reference and post-processing.
Is it possible to make sure that the original formula doesn't expand into multiple cells? Is it possible to force it to remain in just one cell as a "data cell" for future reference by queries without refetching the data again over the network?
=GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31))

My goal is to avoid 3 different network calls for something like:
=AVERAGE(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)))
=MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)))
=MAX(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)))



you can put that in one cell but if initial formula (data that fetches) will change, this one cell will also change. to not change you will need to store it as plaintext (manually)

@player0 I just want to avoid multiple network calls and to neatly store it in a single cell for future reference.

you can compact it like:
=TEXTJOIN(, 1, INDEX(LET(a, 
 GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)), a&{"×", "¤"})))


and then unpack it as:
=INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(D6, "¤")), "×"))


but no idea why this would benefit anything

UPDATE
=LAMBDA(a, REDUCE({"avg","min","max"}, a, LAMBDA(b, c, {b; 
 IFERROR(QUERY(QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(c, "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)), 
 "select avg(Col2),min(Col2),max(Col2)"), "offset 1", ), {"","",""})})))
 (A2:A4)



Is there a way to do this without imploding/exploding everything? I have different tickers on each row. I want a column that has "past 30 days history" so I can post-process that data at my whim. I don't want huge blocks of data that just overwrite each other and take up multiple rows.

@AlanSTACK this is usually done like: =QUERY(QUERY(  {GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31));   GOOGLEFINANCE("GOOG", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31))},,   1), "where Col1 is not null", 1) where you pack your formula with all tickets and put them in array and call the whole thing only once so there are no overlaps/errors etc.

It seems there's a misunderstanding. Picture each row as a different ticker symbol, such as MSFT, GOOG, or AAPL. Each column represents attributes like open, close, high, low, and volume. Now, suppose I want to calculate the average close over the last 30 days. I can't do this directly unless there's a cell in that row holding this data. Similarly, if I need the minimum value of those 30 days, I'd have to issue another query, resulting in many network calls. It would be more efficient to query the data once and have other columns reference it as needed.

My goal is to avoid 3 different network calls for something like =AVERAGE(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31))) and =MIN(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31))) and =MAX(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)))

@AlanSTACK yes, that would be usually done like: =QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE("MSFT", "price", DATE(2024,1,1), DATE(2024,1,31)),   "select min(Col2),max(Col2),avg(Col2)")
